# Unable to install JD-Eclipse in RAD 9

Tags: rad, decompiler, wcs, jd-eclipse

I am trying to install JD-Eclipse plugin in IBM Rational Application Developer Version: 9.5.0.2 . Followed the steps provided in link http://jd.benow.ca/ using Install New Software option in RAD. Getting below exception while installing,

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=IBM Software Delivery Platform com.ibm.sdp.eclipse.ide, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.java.diagnostics.common.datamodel.impl.gui,3.0.12.201611250914
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.java.diagnostics.common.extensions.gui,3.0.12.201611250914
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.coredisplayers,3.0.12.201611250914
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.gui,3.0.12.201611250914
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.java.diagnostics.healthcenter.integration,3.0.12.201611250914
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.batik.dom,1.6.0.v201011041432
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.editor.xml.wtp,4.4.2.v201410272105-8F9F7cFT0z0-TRNfUodYol
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.editor.xml.wtp,4.4.2.v201410272105
```

Please help me out on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Plugin install issue got resolved by below step

Go to Help → Install new software → Here uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”

Answer (score 0):

Try Running RAD as Admin. It solved it for me